# How to compile on save?

Tags: netbeans, save, javafx-2

I would like to compile the project every time I save, but in properties this option is greyed, so for any change I do I have to click save then clean and build.

[image]

How can I do to avoid to clean and build for every code modification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your netbeans project's project.properties like below.

1. Find below line in project.properties file

   **compile.on.save.unsupported.javafx=true**
2. Change this value to set to false

   **compile.on.save.unsupported.javafx=false**
3. After change this file, compile on save option will be enabled and you are good to go.

Comment: The file _project.properties_ is in the directory “nbproject” in your project directory.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer for Apache NetBeans 9, [10](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html), [11](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/nb112.html) using Maven.**

Configuration is set at `nbactions.xml` file, usually it'll look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <packaging>ear</packaging>
            <packaging>ejb</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>package</goal>
        </goals>
    </action>
</actions>
```

To activate the `Compile On Save` option you only need to add the `<netbeans.compile.on.save>` setted to `all`, it'll look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <packaging>ear</packaging>
            <packaging>ejb</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>package</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <netbeans.compile.on.save>all</netbeans.compile.on.save>
        </properties>
    </action>
</actions>
```

### Also...

At latest NB 10 and 11 you may see the warning `It is recommended to install nb-javac Library to improve Java editing experience and enable compile on save` at `Notifications` section:

[image]

You just need to install that plug-in ([nb-javac](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/73454/nb-javac-library)) by clicking on that link, [more info here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Overview%3A+nb-javac), there's currently an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2552) for NB11.2, if you have problems with it try using [beta 3](https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/NetBeans/job/netbeans-TLP/job/netbeans/job/release112/26/artifact/dist/) (or latest)

Comment: in netbeans 11.3 i see that `<netbeans.compile.on.save>all</netbeans.compile.on.save>` goes under `<properties>` tag of 'nb-configuration.xml' file instead.

Comment: also compile on-save, in maven projects, doesnt pickup the changes when running project or single file unlike in ant projects. I always had to clean build maven project before running. so i disabled compile-on-save for maven projects.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose the **Sources** rather than **Build**  from the **Categories**.

Comment: The "Compile on Save" chechBox is available only on Build -> Compiling

Comment: check what kind of project you are creating. In Maven project, for example, you will not get compile option. From the screen shot you are not creating normal Java Application. Or if you are, my IDE is different version than yours. Try to add details.

Comment: Yes, as from my tags, I am using NetBeans and this is a JavaFx 2 project. I have this problem for any JavaFx 2 project while for normal Java project the Compile on Save checkbox is enabled