# Enable Compile on Save option in Netbeans 11

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-11

How can I enable `Compile on Save` in Apache Netbeans IDE 11.0?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOYQE.png]

Output of my `java -version`

```
java version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I tried setting:

- `compile.on.save=true` in `nbproject/private/private.properties`
- `compile.on.save=true` in `nbproject/private.properties`
- `compile.on.save.unsupported.javafx=true` in `nbproject/private.properties`
- `compile.on.save.unsupported.javafx=false` in `nbproject/private.properties`

and possible combinations of these. But not to succeed so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile on save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103371/how-to-compile-on-save)

Comment: The title of the linked duplicate suggests that it is the same question as this one, but it is not. That other question, and its accepted answer, both specifically relate to JavaFX. The OP here is asking how to enable compile-on-save for any type of project, and specifically on NetBeans 11 which was released over six years after the linked question. Furthermore, the solutions for the two questions are completely different. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @LuisLimas No it does not. If you read carefully, I've already tried the options described in the answers of that question which I also included in this question.

Comment: In addition to the nb-javac plugin, keep in mind that your project has to be a maven one (pom.xml based). If your project is a gradle based one, forget about the Compile on save feature in Netbeans for your project :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nbjavac](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/73454/nb-javac-library) plugin needs to be installed. See also [here](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/36af1d6102b35bdd74dcfe0dfbe2935b3c00ba3204ec28aaa5fbc925@%3Cdev.netbeans.apache.org%3E).

Comment: While this is true, it's not the whole story since installing nb-javac will fail on NetBeans 11.0 or 11.1.

Answer (score 6):

TLDR:

- You need to install the nb-javac library to enable compile on save.
- However, due to a NetBeans bug, you must use version 11.2 beta 3 of NetBeans for that to work.

---

You may be seeing this issue because you need to install the **nb-javac** library. To determine whether installation is necessary:

- Open the **Notifications** window by selecting **Window > IDE Tools > Notifications**.
- If installation is required there will be a message stating "*Install nb-javac Library*" in the **Notifications** window:

  [image: nb-javac library]

To install the **nb-javac** library:

- Unfortunately you must use version 11.2 beta 3 (or later) of NetBeans. This is due to an unrelated problem with the installation of **nb-javac**.
- You can download NetBeans 11.2 beta 3 [from this page](https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/NetBeans/job/netbeans-TLP/job/netbeans/job/release112/26/artifact/dist/). The file is named **netbeans-11.2-beta3-bin.zip**. Just download the zip file, then unzip it in a new directory.
- From version 11.2 beta 3 of NetBeans (or later), select the notification in the **Notifications** window.
- Click the link in the right pane with the text "*It is recommended to install nb-javac Library to improve Java editing experience and **enable compile on save***".
- A wizard for installing the library will be shown:

  [image: Wizard]
- Complete the steps in the wizard. Once installation is complete, restart NetBeans.

After restarting NetBeans you should find that:

- The **nb-javac** library has been installed.
- The **Compile on Save** checkbox for your project is enabled.

I could reproduce your problem in NetBeans 11.1, and I have verified that this solution worked for me.

Notes:

- See Bug Report [NETBEANS-2552 Fail to install nb-javac Library on NetBeans 11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2552) for details on why you need to upgrade NetBeans to version 11.2 beta 3 to fix this issue.
- If you prefer not to use a beta release, version 11.2 of NetBeans should be available very soon.
- See these articles for further information on **nb-javac**:

  - ["What's "nb-javac" in Apache NetBeans?"](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-nb-javac-in).
  - [Overview: nb-javac](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Overview%3A+nb-javac)

Comment: How can I install it offline? I have downloaded nb-javac library